# Emacs lisp "shell-command-on-region"

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In GNU Emacs, I want to run a program, figlet, on the currently selected text. I then want to comment the region which is produced.

I have figured out how to do it using the standard Emacs commands:

- set mark with C-<space> at the start of the word
- move cursor to the end of the word
- C-u M-x shell-command-on-region RET figlet RET
- M-x comment-region RET

However, I have failed to work out how to write an Emacs lisp program to do all this. Here is my attempt:

```
(defun figlet-region () 
  (interactive)
  (push-mark)
  (shell-command-on-region "figlet")
  (comment-region (mark) (point))
  (pop-mark)
)

(global-set-key "\C-c\C-f" 'figlet-region)
```

Then `C-<space>; M-x figlet-region` produces garbage:

```
figlet-region: Wrong number of arguments: #[(start end command &optional output-buffer replace error-buffer display-error-buffer) "ÆÇÈ  
\"!É
'jÊ!j;j
0Wb
?Ë`Ì\"Í ÎQÎDRÎÉ!\"&
ffÏ )ãÐqÑ!#Ò#p=¬É$]d|e^|Íed Î ÎD¡ÎÉ!\"&â%&#qÉ$Á&%Ó *Í ÉØ#DÚ#É!\"&*#Ô!#ÕÖ×!8WrÐ!qd`Z'o   ØcÙÉ\"d'Zb)(Úp!)Û!*" [error-buffer small-temporary-file-directory temporary-file-directory exit-status error-file replace make-temp-file expand-file-name "scor" nil ...] 9 1945557 (let (string) (unless (mark) (error "The mark is not set now, so there is no region")) (setq string (read-from-minibuffer "Shell command on region: " nil nil nil (quote shell-command-history))) (list (region-beginning) (region-end) string current-prefix-arg current-prefix-arg shell-command-default-error-buffer t))], 1
```

### Answer

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region b e "figlet" (current-buffer) t)
  (comment-region (mark) (point)))
```

(This is based on Trey Jackson's answer.)

#### Example (Lisp Interaction mode)

```
;;  _   _                 _        
;; | |_| |__   __ _ _ __ | | _____ 
;; | __| '_ \ / _` | '_ \| |/ / __|
;; | |_| | | | (_| | | | |   <\__ \
;;  \__|_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|_|\_\___/
```

#### Example (CPerl mode)

```
#  _   _                 _        
# | |_| |__   __ _ _ __ | | _____ 
# | __| '_ \ / _` | '_ \| |/ / __|
# | |_| | | | (_| | | | |   <\__ \
#  \__|_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|_|\_\___/
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish with the pushing and popping of the marks, I believe you'd get the same functionality by doing this:

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region b e "figlet")
  (comment-region b e))
```

The argument to interactive tells Emacs to pass the region (point and mark) in as the first two arguments to the command.

Comment: note that `shell-command-on-region` may modify the region, so the last line should read `(comment-region (mark) (point))` as in my answer.

Comment: In the form used in my answer, it will not modify the region (unless you're calling it from the buffer `*Shell Command Output*` which is just weird).  If you're going to use `(mark)` and `(point)` - there's no point in passing in the region via arguments, for it will fail to work as expected when *not* called interactively.

Comment: imagine `shell-command-on-region` replaces the region `b`-`e` with an empty string. will then `comment-region` DRT?

Comment: Yes, *if* `shell-command-on-region` were called with more arguments, *then* what you're saying is correct.  But it is *not* (in my example), so your point doesn't apply.  My answer doesn't solve the entirety of his question, but he's figured it out.

Answer (score 9):

It is not a very good idea to use an interactive command like `shell-command-on-region` in a lisp program. You should use [`call-process-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) instead:

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive "r")
  (call-process-region b e "figlet" t t)
  (comment-region (mark) (point)))
```

It should be more resilient against various user options.

Comment: Be aware that using the first "t" after the <command> in the call to 'call-process-region' make the region to be deleted.
The signature of this function is: <start end program &optional *delete* destination display &rest args>

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm not sure where the garbage is coming from, but the error itself is coming from `shell-command-region`. When used in `elisp`, it expects at least 3 arguments, `START` `END` and `COMMAND`.

Also, in general, it is bad practice to mess with the mark in functions. Here is what the doc of push-mark has to say on the subject:

> Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often
>   try to use the mark for the wrong
>   purposes.  See the documentation of
>   `set-mark' for more information.