# Call subprocess with region using command-line argument

Tags: emacs, process

I want to send the region to a python subprocess on stdin, using `command` as the argument of `python -c [command]`. Further I want to insert the result into the current buffer if I have called the function with a prefix argument.

Here's what I've tried:

```lisp
(defun abcdef/python-region (prefix command &optional b e)
  "Call python with `command' and send region on stdin. 
  Insert result if prefix present."
  (interactive "Psr")
  (call-process-region b e "python" prefix t "-c" command))
```

When I try calling it interactively with `M-x abcdef/python-region` I get `Wrong type argument: stringp, t`.

---

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548605/emacs-lisp-shell-command-on-region).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see how you'd get that particular error, but your `interactive` form isn't providing the arguments you need.

It should look something like this:

```
(interactive "P\nsCommand: \nr")
```

> Usually the argument of ‘interactive’ is a string containing a code
>   letter followed optionally by a prompt.  (Some code letters do not
>   use I/O to get the argument and do not use prompts.)  To pass several
>   arguments to the command, concatenate the individual strings,
>   separating them by newline characters.

— <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `interactive`